# Merge content of multiple Excel files into one using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have multiple Excel files with different names in path.

e.g. `C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\report`

Each file has a fixed number of columns.

e.g. `Date | Downtime | Response`

I want to create a new Excel file with merge of all Excel data. New column should be added with client name in which i want to enter file name. Then each Excel file data append below one by one.

e.g. `Client name | Date | Downtime | Response`

Below code can able to append all excel data but now need to add Client name column.

```
$path = "C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\report"

#Launch Excel, and make it do as its told (supress confirmations)
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $True
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path

#Open up a new workbook
$Dest = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()

#Loop through files, opening each, selecting the Used range, and only grabbing the first 5 columns of it. Then find next available row on the destination worksheet and paste the data
ForEach($File in $Files)
{
    $Source = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File.FullName,$true,$true)
    If(($Dest.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Count -eq 1) -and ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Dest.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value2)))
    { 
        #If there is only 1 used cell and it is blank select A1
        [void]$source.ActiveSheet.Range("A1","E$(($Source.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows|Select -Last 1).Row)").Copy()
        [void]$Dest.Activate()
        [void]$Dest.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select()
    }
    Else
    { 
        #If there is data go to the next empty row and select Column A
        [void]$source.ActiveSheet.Range("A2","E$(($Source.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows|Select -Last 1).Row)").Copy()
        [void]$Dest.Activate()
        [void]$Dest.ActiveSheet.Range("A$(($Dest.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows|Select -last 1).row+1)").Select()
    }
    [void]$Dest.ActiveSheet.Paste()
    $Source.Close()
}
$Dest.SaveAs("$path\Merge.xls")
$Dest.close()
$Excel.Quit()
```

Suggest any effective way to do this. Please provide links if available.

Convert XLS to XLSX :

```
$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlWorkbookDefault
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $true
$folderpath = "C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\report\*"
$filetype ="*xls"
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderpath -Include $filetype | 
ForEach-Object `
{
    $path = ($_.fullname).substring(0,($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
    "Converting $path to $filetype..."
    $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($_.fullname)

    $workbook.saveas($path, $xlFixedFormat)
    $workbook.close()
}
$excel.Quit()
$excel = $null
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: SO is not a place where other people rewrite code you found somewhere on the web to your requirements. Being a member for almost 8 years you should know that by now.

Comment: Yes, thats why i write to suggest a way. Don't want anyone to rewrite it. Anyway i am  looking into it. Will update if able to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use the external module `Import-Excel`, you could simply loop through the files like so:

```
$report_directory = ".\reports"

$merged_reports = @()

# Loop through each XLSX-file in $report_directory
foreach ($report in (Get-ChildItem "$report_directory\*.xlsx")) {

    # Loop through each row of the "current" XLSX-file
    $report_content = foreach ($row in Import-Excel $report) {
        # Create "custom" row
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Client name" = $report.Name
            "Date"        = $row."Date"
            "Downtime"    = $row."Downtime"
            "Response"    = $row."Response"
        }
    }

    # Add the "custom" data to the results-array
    $merged_reports += @($report_content)
}

# Create final report
$merged_reports | Export-Excel ".\merged_report.xlsx"
```

Please note that this code is not optimized in terms of performance but it should allow you to get started

Comment: Failed to read C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\report\aucondeco0100-mla-uat.xls
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ImportExcel\5.4.5\ImportExcel.psm1:356 char:20

Comment: Well ... since I don't know how the files look like, I can't say what's the problem. Maybe it's because XLS is an archaic format. You could use something like `ConvertTo-ExcelXlsx $report -Force` to reformat the XLS into XLSX so you may be able to use that XLSX-File in the `Import-Excel`-loop

Comment: ok cool. it just need to convert xls to xlsx file first and then to use your code. I am updating the conversion code in the question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem *.xlsx | ForEach-Object {
$XLSX = Import-XML -Path $_.FullName -Delimiter ","
$FileName = $_.Name

$XLSX | Select-Object *,@{N='Filename';E={$FileName}} | Export-XML $_.FullName -NTI
```

}

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**